# cutting out the hour part (not in 24 hour time) of a date?

Tags: bash, date, unix, compare, hour

My problem is with cutting the hour portion of the date out. 
I am not allowed to use date commands only cut!!!!!
Suppose the date command at that time reads 
Tues Apr 26 17:07:49 PDT 2017
then it should print out 
5:07

I am having a lot of trouble because it is not recognizing a read on an int but rather a string. Been bugging me a long time now...

Here is my code thus far:

```
today=$(date)

echo The date right now is "$today"
echo "The time right now is $(printf '%s\n' "$today" | cut -c 11-19)"
let hour=${today:11:2}
let minute=${today:13:2}

if [[ ${hour} -ge 43200 ]]
        then
        let answer=hour-12

                echo "The correct time is $answer:$minute pm"
fi
```

I calculated 43200 from the number of seconds at 12:00pm
Current output is:

The date right now is Wed Apr 26 21:47:39 PDT 2017

The time right now is  21:47:39

Comment: I suggest first `man date`.

Comment: edited the post, not allowed to use date specific commands

Answer (score 0):

```
let hour=${today:11:2}
let minute=${today:13:2}
```

You have the following string format (with positions):

```
          1         2
0123456789012345678901234567
Wed Apr 26 21:47:39 PDT 2017
           ^ ^
```

That means the two characters at offset 11 are `17` (correct) but the minute is being extracted at offset 13, which is `:0`. The correct extraction for minute would be `${today:14:2}`.

Comment: Thank you for your help from the bottom of my heart. I honestly spent a ton of time on this question but with your guidance I was able to solve it. I truly am eternally grateful for you jumping from one post to another and you helped me immensely. Thank you @paxdiablo